# Is it possible to send/receive hangout message using php?

Tags: php, api, google-hangouts

I am currently building a portal for an organization.  Wondering if it's possible to send message through `HANGOUT API`.  I know I can build mobile app with `GCM` or `APNS`, which will be a lot of work.  So, if it's possible to send message hangout message through php, it will be much easier.  Or, do you have any alternatives for sending notification to users?

Comment: Does Google Hangout have an API?

Comment: Yes, but seems not support text message

Comment: you can build your own messaging system(using [slanger](https://github.com/stevegraham/slanger) ) and use it on your hangout app to push new messages (in realtime) between hangout app and other clients on your native application view.

Answer (score 1):

you could build a api based on: https://github.com/tdryer/hangups currently there is no native php hangout message api